# Remove TabIndicator from PagerTabStrip in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a viewpager that uses a PagerTabStrip to indicate the current page.
However, I don't want the default indicator to be present. (Underline underneath the page title)

I've tried a few different methods to remove it, but none of them seem to work.

> PagerTabStrip pts = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
>    pts.setTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

also

> PagerTabStrip pts = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
>   pts.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));

and

> PagerTabStrip pts = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
>   pts.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

None of these seems to work. Instead it gives me a black indicator instead.
Any help would be appreciated. THanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking at the source of PagerTabStrip. I have found the following method:

```
/**
 * Set whether this tab strip should draw a full-width underline in the
 * current tab indicator color.
 *
 * @param drawFull true to draw a full-width underline, false otherwise
 */
public void setDrawFullUnderline(boolean drawFull) {
    mDrawFullUnderline = drawFull;
    mDrawFullUnderlineSet = true;
    invalidate();
}
```

I have not tested this, but I suppose this should work. Leave a comment if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it working with your help. I'll post my final source in a bit once I confirm everything is working.

Comment: setDrawFullUnderline divides the PagerTitleStrip. I was trying to remove the Tab Indicator underline setTabIndicatorColor, Android Docs says "Color to set as an 0xRRGGBB value. The high byte (alpha) is ignored."

Comment: Tested, this is not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) is what you need. It has the same functionality, just without the underline color.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html), you can set the Indicator Color to same color of Background [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)